# How to split the nested json using jolt specification in Apache Nifi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying to prepare jolt specification. Can you please help me out.

Input:

```json
{
  "VulnId": 90089,
  "source": "WERUA",
  "sourceId": "WERT38173",
  "StateDescription": "Not Being Used",
  "Status": true,
  "DurationInDays": "69",
  "Assessments": [
    {
      "id": 357978,
      "name": "2023-02-05T10:00:15.620",
      "date": "2023-02-05T10:00:15",
      "type": "System"
    },
    {
      "id": 370904,
      "name": "2023-03-14T10:00:05.872 ",
      "date": "2023-03-14T10:00:05",
      "type": "System"
    }
  ],
  "Tags": [
    {
      "id": 47954778,
      "name": "RS_Co",
      "category": "Custom",
      "created": "2023-06-19T16:59:37",
      "updated": "2023-06-19T16:59:37"
    },
    {
      "id": 479547767,
      "name": "RS_Co",
      "category": "Custom",
      "created": "2023-06-19T16:59:37",
      "updated": "2023-06-19T16:59:37"
    }
  ],
  "workflowDistribution_latestSystemWorkflows": [
    {
      "generatedId": "SY00989",
      "type": "SYSTEM",
      "acronym": "SYS",
      "state": "Approved"
    },
    {
      "generatedId": "SY8989",
      "type": "SYSTEM",
      "acronym": "SYS",
      "state": "Approved"
    }
  ],
  "firstAssignedOnDate": null
}
```

Expected Output:

```json
[
  {
    "VulnId": 90089,
    "source": "WERUA",
    "sourceId": "WERT38173",
    "StateDescription": "Not Being Used",
    "Status": true,
    "DurationInDays": "69",
    "Assessments": {
      "id": 357978,
      "name": "2023-02-05T10:00:15.620 ",
      "date": "2023-02-05T10:00:15",
      "type": "System"
    },
    "Tags": {
      "id": 47954778,
      "name": "RS_Co",
      "category": "Custom",
      "created": "2023-06-19T16:59:37",
      "updated": "2023-06-19T16:59:37"
    },
    "workflowDistribution_latestSystemWorkflows": {
      "generatedId": "SY00989",
      "type": "SYSTEM",
      "acronym": "SYS",
      "state": "Approved"
    },
    "firstAssignedOnDate": null
  },
  {
    "VulnId": 90089,
    "source": "WERUA",
    "sourceId": "WERT38173",
    "StateDescription": "Not Being Used",
    "Status": true,
    "DurationInDays": "69",
    "Assessments": {
      "id": 370904,
      "name": "2023-03-14T10:00:05.872 ",
      "date": "2023-03-14T10:00:05",
      "type": "System"
    },
    "Tags": {
      "id": 479547767,
      "name": "RS_Co",
      "category": "Custom",
      "created": "2023-06-19T16:59:37",
      "updated": "2023-06-19T16:59:37"
    },
    "workflowDistribution_latestSystemWorkflows": {
      "generatedId": "SY8989",
      "type": "SYSTEM",
      "acronym": "SYS",
      "state": "Approved"
    },
    "firstAssignedOnDate": null
  }
]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following transformation :

```json
[
  { // put the non-array elements to an individual elements(namely "Others")
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "Others.&",
      "Assessments|Tags|workflowDistributio*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Assessments|Tags|workflowDistributio*": {
        "*": {
          "@2,Others": { "*": "[&1].&" }, // go two levels up the tree to reach the level of the "Others" object
          "*": "[&1].&2.&" // group by indexes of the arrays by using [&1]
                           // bring the keys of the arrays by using &2 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only one components from the arrays with repeating values
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```